# getResourceAsStream doesnt devlier any Stream

Tags: eclipse, jar, stream, resources

Trying to make an executable .jar with resources inside of it. Quick question:
Why do i get NullPointerException for this code?

```
    String filename = "/settings.xml"
    try (InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));)
    {
        settingArray = (boolean[]) xStream.fromXML(reader);
    }
```

I use Eclipse and the file settings.xml is in the root directory of my project. The following code works perfectly, but not after an export to jar:

```
    try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)))
    {
        settingArray = (boolean[]) xStream.fromXML(reader);
    }
```

Comment: Making following change: filename = "/../settings.xml" has no success :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be loaded using `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/settings.xml")`, the file must not be at the root of your project. At runtime Java doesn't know and care about your eclipse project containing the sources of your application.

What it cares about is the runtime classpath. The file must be at the root of the classpath. To be there, the file should be

- at the root of the jar file if you execute the application from the jar
- at the root of the bin (or classes, or whatever you chose to name the directory where eclipse stores the compiled .class files) directory if you execute the application from the IDE. To be there, the easiest way is to place the file at the root of the sources directory, in the default package. Eclipse will "compile" this source file to the bin directory by copying it.